# How to add multiple fonts to a single line of text with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

In plant classification the family-genus-species is normally written in italics with any variety in normal text.

*Rosaceae Sorbus aucuparia* 'Fastigiata'

I'm trying to achieve this in c# using the iTextSharp library. Could anyone help?
I've made two different font objects. Added each one to two different chunk objects and then added the chunks to a phrase object before finally adding the phrase to a table cell.

Current output is the whole line is in italics.

*Rosaceae Sorbus aucuparia 'Fastigiata'*

```
iTextSharp.text.Font fontHeader = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 15f);
iTextSharp.text.Font fontHeaderItalic = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 15f, iTextSharp.text.Font.ITALIC);

Phrase phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(plant.strFamily + " " + plant.strGenus + " " + plant.strSpecies, fontHeaderItalic));
if(plant.strVariety != null)
    phrase.Add(new Chunk(" '" + plant.strVariety + "'", fontHeader));

tableHeader.AddCell(new PdfPCell(phrase) { Border = 0 });
```

Comment: You talk about iTextSharp, but we don't call it like that anymore. Two years ago, we changed the name to iText for .NET. You are using iText 5, but we're already at iText 7. Answering your question for iText 5 takes 10 minutes, answering your question for iText 7 only takes 3. If you're interested in an iText 7 answer, I'm willing to spend 3 minutes. I won't spend 10 minutes on the iText 5 answer.

Comment: No worries, thanks anyway.